# get request parameter from a for each loop

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, jstl

I have a JSP with a table like this

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
    <th>Step</th>
    <th>Date</th>
</tr>
<c:forEach var="myVar" items="${sessionScope.myBean.myList}" varStatus="status">
    <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="index" value="${status.count}" disabled></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="date" value="${myVar.date}"></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
```

This table is inside a form, with a submit input tag.

Let's say myList (list attribute in the bean myBean) contains 2 elements, my table correctly displays two lines, with step and date on each line.

Let's say I edit both lines to enter a date on each one of them.

When I click the submit input, how can I get both entered dates ? And how can I know into which item from the bean's list they shall be stored ?

I looked in debug at request.getParameterNames() after POSTing my form, but it only contains one "date" parameter.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `HttpServletRequest#getParameterValues()`. The values are in the same order as the HTML input elements appear in the HTML DOM tree.

```
String[] dates = request.getParameterValues("date");
// ...
```