# JQuery keyup on dynamic textboxes on dynamic form

Tags: jquery

I have a form that has a button that will trigger JQuery to create an additional form on the same page.

This 2nd form has two text boxes: first one is `Account`, second one is `BankAddress`

When the `BankAddress` gets focus, another button is created to add more `BankAddress` text boxes.  It works fine and the `keyup` trigger also works fine *until* I added code to add index to the end of the `BankAddress` `Name` & `Id` so that I could identify each box.

Any Ideas?

**JS**

```js
function doAddMoreBank(form) { 
    $('<p class="pTxtFields"><label for="newBankAddress">&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp</label>' + 
      '<input type="text" value="New Switft Address" class="newBankAddress inputNumTextBox1 keyup-charNumOnly" maxlength="23">' +
      '<span class="BankAddrSpan errorStyle"><span></p>').insertBefore("#idAddMoreBank");  
     addBankNames(this.form);
}


function addBankNames(form) {       
    $('.newBankAddress').each(function(i) {
        $(this).attr('id', 'newBankAddress' + (i + 1));
     $(this).attr('name', 'newBankAddress' + (i + 1));
    });
}
 
// $(document).on('keyup', "[id^=newBankAddress]", function() { 
$(document).on('keyup', "#newBankAddress1", function() { 
    alert=("I will do Editing " );      
});
```

Comment: does your console show any errors in javascript or jquery?

Comment: Please submit super basic html for this question. I want to address something and need to make sure my assumption is right.

Comment: and side question.. do are you using php?

Answer (score 0):

This is a little off topic, but you really don't seem to be using  your functions to full power.

You're passing `form` to two of these functions and not using it in either that I can see. I might be overlooking it, but deff not seeing it. You're using ids when you should be using some form of dynamic selection so that you can reuse these functions without depending on the markup, but that isn't super important right this second.

```
function doAddMoreBank(form) {  
    $('<p class="pTxtFields"><label for="newBankAddress">&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp</label>' + 
    '<input type="text" value="New Switft Address" class="newBankAddress inputNumTextBox1 keyup-charNumOnly" maxlength="23">' +
    '<span class="BankAddrSpan errorStyle"><span></p>').insertBefore("#idAddMoreBank");     
    addBankNames(form);
}
```

`this.form` isn't really targeting anything.... unless you show html markup to prove that you were doing this correctly just passing `form` should be efficient enough.

```
function addBankNames(form) {       
        $('.newBankAddress').each(function(i) {
            $(this).attr('id', 'newBankAddress' + (i + 1));
            $(this).attr('name', 'newBankAddress' + (i + 1));
        });
}
```

Here you were targeting a specific ID if that ID doesn't exist ever it won't work. Instead target the class and this would work for all bank addresses. Without question.

```
$(document).on('keyup', ".newBankAddress", function() { 

    alert=("I will do Editing " ); 

});
```

**EDIT**

BTW... If you're using some server side logic with your post variables and what not there is an opportunity to make this script better and much more dynamic. Also get rid of that pesky `$.each()`

Literally change the `doAddMoreBank` function:

```
function doAddMoreBank(form) {  
    $('<p class="pTxtFields"><label for="newBankAddress">&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp</label>' + 
    '<input type="text" value="New Switft Address" name="newBankAddress[]" class="newBankAddress inputNumTextBox1 keyup-charNumOnly" maxlength="23">' +
    '<span class="BankAddrSpan errorStyle"><span></p>').insertBefore("#idAddMoreBank"); 
}
```

Just by adding `newBankAddress[]` you can have as many bank addresses as you want added. In your server side you would loop through each version and deal with it as needed. You will have to decide what is the best way for this because it may be necessary to do it one of two ways.

After doing this you can drop the function `addBankNames`

Comment: Let me say Thanks first. I'm a newbie so apologies. I got rid of the (form). Server Side is JSP. I like the idea of using name="newBankAddress[]" but does it work with JSP ? I added and tested adding mutiple rows and my logs only say it sees only 1 , identified as = newBankAddress[] . Also when I inspect element  using chrome tools its indetified the same way = newBankAddress[],

Comment: sec never seen JSP before. I'm researching now.

Comment: @Jeter2015 [does this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14695816/get-request-parameter-from-a-for-each-loop) make sense to you???